# spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE-yarn, submit error

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spring-xd

If anyone has seen this issue before, please help me.
Here is my steps.
And, do I need to start from opt/spring-xd-1.3.1/xd/bin/xd-admin and xd-container before running below commands from opt/spring-xd-1.3.1.RELEASE-yarn/bin/

Thank you in advance.

1. bin/xd-yarn push
2. bin/xd-yarn submit => having below error.

Error executing a spring application; nested exception is org.springframework.yarn.YarnSystemException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is:

Comment: Can you share your `spring.hadoop` configuration, typically defined in `config\servers.yml`. Also, what Hadoop distro/version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this issue has been fixed. The issue come from duplicated config for HDFS from servers.yml.